# How do I get the current date from my phone?

Tags: java, android-studio

So, my first app will be a personal one to help me meet deadlines. As you would imagine it is going to be very date oriented.

So, how do I grab the current date from my phone/emulator?

**Bonus points** if you can explain how to put it into an integer.

Any link or tutorial would be super great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this solution:Date dt = new Date();
                    int hours = dt.getHours();
                    int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                    int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                    String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; but it is dericated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456397/how-do-i-get-the-current-date-from-my-phone

Comment: try `dt.getTime()` it returns a Long.  Learn to read the javadocs

Comment: Sure will. Once I get some formal schooling hopefully all of this will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the time of your phone by creating a calender.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

This stores your actual time. If you want to get the date in a number, just us this:

```
long timeInANumber = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

You need to use a long instead of a integer, because this number is so big. A long is like a integer, but it can store greater values.
The number you get (called **UNIX Timestamp**) represents the count of milliseconds since 00:00 Janurary 1st, 1970.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help! You're the man.